# Problemn with MultiPage app that adds react widget, how to add it to other pages not only the index.html

Tags: reactjs

I built a normal HTML/JS/CSS website and am Adding a widget( a code form made with react ) that I compile and export as a js and css to the index.html page by doing so:

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And I"m compiling the app with:

```js
    //yarn parcel , or npm run parcel
    "parcel": "parcel build src/index.js --no-minify --no-source-maps -d widget && cp build/static/css/*.css widget/index.css",
```

React js script that get's the component and then add it to the element with id.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
  (<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>),
  app
);
```

After compiling I tried to make a secondpage serving it in another route, like blog.html and add the component too as I did with head and body, but the page remains blank. What could it be ? ( there are no logs in the console).

```js
//the first html served
files_routes.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('index.html', { root: '../build' })
});

//the second html which doesn't work
files_routes.get('/blog', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('blog.html', { root: '../build' })
});
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing all of your code.  What does blog.html look like?  Does it have an HTML element in it with the id="app" (since that's what your render call is targeting)? 
 Are there any network requests that failed in the dev console?

Comment: blog.html was a copy paste of the index.html with other name

Comment: Can you give us a repro on codesandbox? I can’t tell if the issue is with react or parcel or the dev web server.

Comment: @James I tried to do a Proof of Concept and it worked here: https://github.com/afa7789/react-mpa-test-widget

I'll add more stuff to the code to see If I can find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate the issue in the newer code base. So I'll be closing this question...